# Does this behavior have a formal name, and if so, what is it?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

This is related to the issue asked about in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true).

For the sake of this question, let's assume that we have a variable v that can have any value from the set of values

> "a", "b", "c", ..., "z"

In this case then the programmers wants to have specific code executed when the value of `v` is **not** `"x"`, `"y"`, or `"z"`.

So the following IF statement is constructed:

> if (v != "x" || v != "y" || v != "z") {//do something}

Above statement would always return true, due to that the 3 conditions using negation are checked independently of each other.

Consequently, at any given time, any single one of the 3 conditions can evaluate to TRUE, leading to the entire IF statement evaluating to TRUE.

Anyway so the question I wanted to ask is, does this behavior or situation have a formal name, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In all programming languages, the `if` statement you give is true, since `v` can't be simultaneously equal to three different things so it's guaranteed that at least two of the conditions are true. And Boolean OR _by definition_ evaluates to true if at least one of its arguments is true. So I'm not sure what behaviour you're talking about.

Comment: And the condition that's normally expressed as "not `"x"`, `"y"` or `"z"`" would be written `!(v=="x" || v=="y" || v=="z")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In many programming languages above statement always returns true, due to that the 3 conditions using negation are checked independently of each other.

It returns true not just due to "that the 3 conditions using negation are checked independently of each other", but because the expression `(v != "x" || v != "y" || v != "z")` is always necessarily true. In logic such expressions are called *[tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic))*, i.e. a formula that is true in every possible interpretation (Wikipedia).

But "this behavior or situation" does not have a special name in programming and is usually considered as a programming error.

Comment: [Logic error](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error) - it has the simple name.